Can I customize UI when using credential manager Authenticate users with Sign in with Google
I am working on supporting Sign in with Google. Now, I can successfully get the idToken using Credential Manager by following this doc: https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg. Can I customize UI when using credential manager Authenticate users with Sign in with Google?

No; there are no developer-driven customization possible for the UI that is shown by Credential Manager APIs. Curious: what kind of customizations are you looking for?

Thanks for the info :) Maybe just customize the style and the color of the dialog/bottomsheet.

We use the Dynamic Theme/Colors so users, based on their personalization, can influence that. It is not customizable by developers so that users see the same identical UI no matter what app they use, which gives them a familiarity with the product and an added level of trust. OEMs (say, Samsung) can style that differently to match their overall system UI.

@mohammadfakhraee There is no reason to post the same question in multiple threads.
